# How to remove Dot (.) between Numbers in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a file like this in Notepad++

```
A;N;000.30.133;Stechbeitel mit Holzheft 28mm;;PCE;2;100
A;N;000.30.142;Stechbeitel mit Holzheft 30mm;;PCE;2;100
A;N;000.30.150;Stechbeitel mit Holzheft 35mm;;PCE;2;100
```

And I want To delete (.) between the numbers and be like this:

```
A;N;00030133;Stechbeitel mit Holzheft 28mm;;PCE;2;100
A;N;00030142;Stechbeitel mit Holzheft 30mm;;PCE;2;100
A;N;00030150;Stechbeitel mit Holzheft 35mm;;PCE;2;100
```

How Can i do it?
Thanks Alot

Comment: Go to `Search` > `Replace`, in the new window under **"Find what"** you type `.` (the dot only), leave **"Replace with"** empty(!) click **Replace** or **Replace All** - This should do the trick. The idea is to find all occurances of a dot (.) and replace them with nothing.  FYI: this does not appear to be the best forum for these kind of questions. Stack Overflow is for programming related questions. That's probably the reason for the downvotes

Comment: First at all Thanks for your reply.Maybe I did not explain properly. I have File With 87737 lines . Another Example of my File:   A;N;909.73.582;Gew.Schr.Ms.nick.pol.  ;;PCE,2 ;500               A;N;108.67.420;Griff chr.matt/chr.pol.95x26mm;;PCE;2;100  I want to delete the (.) just from The Number After A;N .

Answer (score 4):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\d)     # positive lookbehind, zero length assertion that makes sure we have a digit before
\.          # a dot, have to be escaped
(?=\d)      # positive lookahead, zero length assertion that makes sure we have a digit after
```

**Result for given example:**

```
A;N;00030133;Stechbeitel mit Holzheft 28mm;;PCE;2;100
A;N;00030142;Stechbeitel mit Holzheft 30mm;;PCE;2;100
A;N;00030150;Stechbeitel mit Holzheft 35mm;;PCE;2;100
```

Answer (score 0):

Search string "[0-9]{1}[\.]{1}[0-9]{1}" - digit, dot, digit

Replace str - sorry, I don't know)

Comment: Why are you answering if you don't know? That doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 0):

You actually just need to replace "." with "empty" (not literally empty but it means not any characters/letters/numbers.)

Steps:
0) Open your file with Notepad++.
1) Click Ctrl + H
2) Fill **Find What** with "."
3) Fill **Replace with** with "empty"
4) Click **Replace** (to replace one by one) or **Replace All** (to replace everything at once).

Comment: They want to replace dot `.` between digits only. Yours remove all dots.